# How to get the value that is in the array instead of true with in_array?

Tags: php

How could I receive the return with the value that is inside the array, and not true? in_array() does this?

```
$type = 'ai';

$types = ['analitycs', 'log_in_info', 'auto_dark_mode', 'ai', 'notification'];

echo in_array($type, $types); //my wish "ai", my reality "1";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for it, that returns the key and use that key to access it:

```
echo $types[array_search($type, $types)];
```

Or if `$type` is found you can just access it:

```
echo in_array($type, $types) ? $type : 'not found';  // or whatever
```

Comment: Okay, trank you brother!!